# jQuery accordion menu - trouble hiding submenus by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery accordion-style menu and I've very nearly got it working but I've been stuck for hours trying to work out why the submenus are showing by default when the page loads.

I've tried hiding them using CSS and for some reason they then won't slide down at all. I've also tried hiding them in the jQuery and have the same problem.

I've obviously gone wrong somewhere but I can't work out where.

I've created a JSFiddle for the HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/rcord/Gd7DM/7/

My jQuery is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#mobnav > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#mobnav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideToggle('normal');
      }
      if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#mobnav ul ul:visible').slideToggle('normal');
        checkElement.slideToggle('normal');
      }
      if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length === 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
     });
    });
```

Thank you!

edit: Thank you very much to the two people who've answered - that works perfectly. I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not sure where I'm supposed to say thank you since it says not to use comments...

Answer (score 0):

Change your menu selector from `nav ul` to `#mobnav > ul` otherwise you're toggling all lists inside the nav with the first click

```
$(function () {
    var pull = $('#pull');
    menu = $('#mobnav > ul');
    $(menu).on('load').hide();
    menuHeight = menu.height();
    $(pull).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });
...
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/Gd7DM/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your top navigation selector `menu = $('nav ul');` is selecting all the `ul` elements, change it to `#mobnav > ul instead

```
var pull = $('#pull');
menu = $('#mobnav > ul');
$(menu).on('load').hide();
menuHeight = menu.height();
$(pull).on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('p')
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9zjBk/)